# How to make DateTime independent from the current culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I cam trying to convert a datetime to string and back, but making it so that it works for all cultures.

I basically have a Textbox (tbDateTime) and a label (lbDateTime). The label tells the user, in which format the software expects the input of tbDateTime. The input of the Textbox will be used for an MySQL command.

Currently it works like this:

```
lbDateTime.Text = "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss";   // I live in germany
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(tbDateTime.Text);
String filter = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Now my question:

- Is it possible to determine the format-string for lbDateTime.Text based on the current culture?
- Which format does the Convert.ToDateTime function uses?

I hope you can help me. I have actually no pc here to test different cultures, so I'm very afraid that I make something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `Convert.ToDateTime` method you can use the `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` methods. Both allow you to pass a culture that tells how you expect the date to be formatted.

The `DateTime.ParseExact` method also allows you to specify the format you expect, so you can parse more or less any format with this method.

**Edit:**
Regarding `Convert.ToDateTime`. The documentation says that the current culture is used when parsing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx

The current culture can be found using the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property.

**Edit2:**
Oh. You may also want to use `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` if you are unsure whether the given format is invalid.

**Edit3:**
Lots of edits here... I see that you want to determine the culture string that matches the date the user has entered. There is no general solution that is guaranteed to work here. Say for instance that the user has entered the date 01.02.11. There is no way to be certain if this date is in day.month.year or month.day.year or year.month.day and so on.

The best you can do is to have a list of expected input cultures and start with the most likely and try to parse the date using that. If that fails, you can try the second most likely and so on...

But this is really not recommended. Either give the user an expected format, or better, use a date input box that ensures that you receive the selected date in an appropriate format.

Answer (score 5):

The `Convert.ToDateTime` method will call `DateTime.Parse` to parse the string, using the current culture (`CultureInfo.Current`).

You can specify a culture when parsing the string. Example:

```
DateTime data = DateTime.Parse(tbDateTime.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` (or `DateTime.TryParseExact`) to parse the string using a custom date format. Example:

```
DateTime data = DateTime.ParseExact(tbDateTime.Text, "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: DateTime.Parse is throwing error when converting from Arabic date to en-US datetime. "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". how to get rid of this? any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
// Specify the current language (used in the current system you are working on)
CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString());
// Specify the language that we need
CultureInfo myLanguage = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

// Adapt the DateTime here, we will use the current time for this example
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
// The date in the format that we need
string myDate = DateTime.Parse(currentDate.ToString(), currentCulture).ToString(myLanguage);
```