# Store DateTime as culture independent in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I currently have a challenge of storing a DateTime value in a NVarChar field so that it's culture independent.

I've read that you can convert the value to an int by using `CONVERT(int, GETDATE(), 112)` which should make it culture independent but the former statement doesn't store the time.

What is the industry standard of storing a DateTime as culture independent?

- EDIT

Please note that I can't use DateTime in my scenario. It must be NVarChar.

- EDIT 2

Alright, found the answer to my own question.

To convert a DateTime to it's binary(8) raw format:
convert(binary(8), GETDATE())

I then store the value in a VARCHAR field as follows:
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), convert(binary(8), GETDATE()), 2)

To retrieve it back from the varchar field and convert it to DateTime:
CONVERT(DateTime,CONVERT(binary(8), [TextField], 2))

As var as I'm concerned, this will store a DateTime as culture independent.

- EDIT 3

It seems like user Kaf has the best solution. I will rather use format 126 to convert it to text and then back to DateTime from text.

Thanks everyone and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make DateTime independant from the current culture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893937/how-to-make-datetime-independant-from-the-current-culture)

Comment: I've looked at the possible duplicate but that one refers to C#. I'm asking specifically about SQL Server.

Comment: Store as the appropriate data type for the task - `datetime`. The culture should only come into play when *presenting* the data to the user. Using inappropriate data types will give you myriad programming, formatting & performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you `CANNOT` store date as Datetime, you can use *`style 126`* which gives `ISO8601 format` (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces)`). I think it is culture independent.

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21543)**

```
select convert(nvarchar(50),getdate(),126)
```

Best thing is to store Date as a DateTime/Date type.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` data type to store date and time values. They are stored in binary format in the database and are culture independent.

You can read more on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.100).aspx

More on how SQL Server stores the datetime values: "It uses 8 bytes to store a datetime value—the first 4 for the date and the second 4 for the time." (from: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree with you but in the current scenario I need to store the DateTime as a NVarChar field and not DateTime. It's a long story :)

Comment: If it's for your own purpose, you can even go for a custom format.

Comment: I don't really want to go down the route of creating custom formats. I was just wondering if there is a "raw" type format that stores a DateTime before applying any Culture.

Comment: Yes, but it's a binary format: "It uses 8 bytes to store a datetime value—the first 4 for the date and the second 4 for the time." (from: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery)

Comment: Exactly! I want to store that raw binary(8) value as a string so that I can retrieve it at another point and convert it to DateTime.

Comment: So you want to simulate storing as datetime but not using datetime data type? Confusing, I must say...

Comment: It may be confusing but I think that is the way to go if you want to store it as cultural independent text. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Datetime IS culture independent. Simply. Converting it to a string for display is a completely separate issue to storage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get this idea to store a date in a varchar field so that it is 'culture independant'. dateTime data type is culture independant. What is culture dependent is the way date values are displayed:

```
MM/dd/YYYY
dd/MM/YYYY
YYYY-MM-DD
etc
```

But, if the display changes, the underlying value itself is still the same ... and this is why you can easily 'convert' dates from one format to another....

So, for the sake of simplicity, I do strongly advise you to switch to a culture-independant, datetime field. Otherwise any further use of this field's content (calculation, display, print out, etc) will be a real PITA ...